# why does the staking.sol contract have permissions on the notifyReward function?

Tags: solidity, defi, staking

In both this [example](https://github.com/Synthetixio/synthetix/blob/develop/contracts/StakingRewards.sol#L113) and this [example](https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/staking-rewards/) the `notifyReward` function has a modifier that only allows the `owner` to distribute rewards.

```
    function notifyRewardAmount(
        uint _amount
    ) external onlyOwner updateReward(address(0)) {
        if (block.timestamp >= finishAt) {
            rewardRate = _amount / duration;
        } else {
            uint remainingRewards = (finishAt - block.timestamp) * rewardRate;
            rewardRate = (_amount + remainingRewards) / duration;
        }

        require(rewardRate > 0, "reward rate = 0");
        require(
            rewardRate * duration <= rewardsToken.balanceOf(address(this)),
            "reward amount > balance"
        );

        finishAt = block.timestamp + duration;
        updatedAt = block.timestamp;
    }
```

Why would they do this and why not allow anyone to distribute rewards? Specifically, is there a situation in which funds could be stolen if anyone can call this function?

Comment: maybe ask him here and tell us why :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ-IRzCYSXI

Comment: Probably, because the contracts were designed in a way the rewards can only be modified by the "owner".